# collective.elasticsearch - plone install fails

Tags: elasticsearch, plone, buildout

I am trying to install collective.elasticsearch as an "add-on" into plone by adding it into the eggs and zcml sections of buildout as stated by the installation instructions on the github site. The buildout log is telling me that it installed succesfully but plone fails to start up. When I try to start plone in debug mode, it fails with the following error line:

```
ZopeXMLConfigurationError: File "/var/db/zope/plone43/zeocluster/parts/client1/etc/package-includes/006-collective.elasticsearch-configure.zcml", line 1.0-1.68
    IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/db/zope/plone43/buildout-cache/eggs/collective.elasticsearch-1.0-py2.7.egg/collective/elasticsearch/configure.zcml'
```

Can anyone help me figure out why the configure.zcml file is missing or what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the the add-on has has been badly packaged (commonly: the MANIFEST.in file is missing or not proper).

1. Open an issue to the owner: https://github.com/collective/collective.elasticsearch/issues
2. Use the development version, taking the source from github directly (you'll need to activate it in development mode)

Comment: I opened an issue and will try to install the dev version. thank you for your help!

Comment: There is no release of the package. I don't understand how he was able to get this error message.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is provided in: https://github.com/collective/collective.elasticsearch/issues/3

There is no release of collective.elasticsearch. I don't know how the questioner was able to get the error he did since adding collective.elasticsearch to the eggs section of buildout right now will produce a buildout error unless you're using a clone of the git repo.

Comment: Uh... that's weird. However the MANIFEST file is really missing!